# Get private key from a BigInteger in NBitcoin

Tags: c#, nbitcoin

Is there a way to create new "Key" object from an existing BigInteger?

Something like this?

```
var bigInt = new BigInteger(934157136952);
Key key = new Key(bigInt);
```

I tried searching documentation. But couldn't find.

**Update 1**

I also tried this. It gave me an exception with the message "Invalid String".

```
Key key = Key.Parse(bigInt.ToString(), Network.Main);
```

Seems It needed base58 string as the first argument.

```
Key key = Key.Parse(new Key().GetWif(Network.Main).ToString(), Network.Main); // Works fine
```

Comment: Key should have exactly 32 bytes, while BigInteger can have any number of bytes in binary representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you create a Key instance using a `byte []`. See the `Key` implementation of NBitcoin [here](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/Key.cs#L114)

C# supports converting `BigInteger` to `byte` arrays.
So your code could hypothetically look like this:

```
byte [] bytes = new BigInteger(934157136952).ToByteArray();
Key key = new Key(bytes);
```

The other parameters are optional.
However, in the `Key` implementation, you can see that your `Key` must be 32 bytes long. See [line 14](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/blob/master/NBitcoin/Key.cs#L14). So your example will throw an `ArgumentException`.

So creating an instance of `BigInteger` with a `long` wont work and you should instead parse a `string`. The code below gives a 32 byte `BigInteger` and compiles successfully on my machine.

```
byte[] bytes = BigInteger.Parse("11725344435539341571369527625736255434253725643527635436353563846746536545463").ToByteArray();
Key key = new Key(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(key.PubKey);
//prints : 0391c33d7a367471827b59372e79f7d727ec81ddf2abd5762c91151fe5a2b49f92
```

**Update 1**

Best thing do to covert a byte array of the BigInteger is to add leading zeros as follows.

```
byte [] byteArr = new BigInteger(934157136952).ToByteArray();
byte zero = (new BigInteger(0)).ToByteArray()[0]; // getting the byte representation of zero in the same encoding as BigInterger.ToByteArray()
for (int i = 0; i < byteArr.Length; i++)
{
      byteArr32[i] = byteArr[i];
}
for (int i = byteArr.Length; i < 32-(byteArr.Length); i++)
{
      byteArr32[i] = zero; // leading zero means trailing zeros to the array.
}
Key key = new Key(byteArr32);
```

**Update 2**

C# provides a 1-line solution to resizing arrays *in-situ*. The result will be zero padded by default for byte arrays.

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(934157136952).ToByteArray();
Array.Resize<byte>(ref bytes, 32);
Key key = new Key(bytes);
```

Comment: You cannot require using only BigIntegers which are represented by exactly 32 bytes (because that removes a lot of valid keys). Instead, if `ToByteArray()` returns less than 32 bytes - you have extend it to 32 bytes with zeroes.

Comment: Good point. So I have added the update 1 so that below 32 length byte arrays can be converted into a 32 bit byte array.

Comment: I do not disagree. In fact, key derivation would typically invlove a KDF to make the result more cryptographically secure so zero padding is a common technique. I have added a 1 line solution using Array.Resize<T>(T[], Int32)

Comment: Title is about private key...